How to add vertical line between two tabs?
need vertical line (|) between the tabs.
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header I">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </p>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
        <p>
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium...
        </p>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
        <p>
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos...
        </p>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView> 

I need output like the below,

using PrimeNG in angular 18

You can use the ::after pseudo selector to position the divider at the right and top of the li tag (set this to position: relative). Then we set the height needed and width to 1px then position it based on our requirements.
.custom-divider {
    ul.p-tabview-nav > li:not(.p-tabview-ink-bar) {
            position: relative;
            &::after {
            content: '';
            height: 20px;
            width: 1px;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top: 15px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    }
}

Stackblitz Demo
